# sql, autocomplete, Full-Text-Search with filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, autocomplete, full-text-search

I am building a small social network site. I am using SQL sever and linq 2 entities. My users can write their friends names in messages and I want to auto-complete the users names, but only with names of users that are their friends. Can I do that with full Text Search? because I didn't see a way to use the where clause in combination with the FTS. help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? Firebird? DB2? (Note: *SQL* is **not** a DBMS, it's a language)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL SERVER. thx!

Answer (score 0):

getting all the friends names to the client and making that auto complete search in client side can be more efficient.

Comment: depending on how many friends there are that could be a lot of data to trasmit to the client each time the page loads

Comment: @mashtagidi not sure, haven't done the math. But if you take 1000 friends, let's assume first and last names then that is 2000 extra "words" to send every time the page is reloaded plus 1000 delimiters, unless you cache them. It also assumes that the users computer can handle the javascript to process those 1000 names. I'm not sure at what point for your program and audience the number of friends becomes to big.

Answer (score 0):

Cache all friends from DB in server-side part of your application, then get the list for auto-complete with Jquery/your_favorite_ajax_library. Querying DB after every letter typed from client is an excellent way to completely kill any performance.

Comment: ok. I have also a autocomplete search for brand names which is around  1,000,000 records. What I thought of doing is get the results through Sql FreeTextSearch directly from db. Do you think it's a bad idea?